# changing properties graphs in igraph R

Tags: r, csv, graph, igraph, adjacency-matrix

I'm implementing community detection in networks and have been trying to plot my network as a graph in R. I have two `.csv` files (`adj.csv` & `communities.csv`), `adj.csv` contains adjacency matrix of graph `communities.csv` has list of vertices that should be grouped together.

> adj.csv:
>
> 0,1,1,2,1,1,0,1,2,2,1,1,0,0,1,0,0
>
> 1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0
>
> 1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,0,1,1,0,1
>
> 2,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0
>
> 1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0
>
> 1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,2
>
> 0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
>
> 1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,2,1,1,0,1,0,0,0
>
> 2,1,2,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0
>
> 2,0,2,1,1,0,0,2,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0
>
> 1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,2,1,0,0,0,1
>
> 1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,2
>
> 0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0
>
> 0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0
>
> 1,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
>
> 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
>
> 0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,1,0
>
> communities.csv:
>
> 11,10,7,4,3
>
> 12,5
>
> 13,9
>
> 14,1,0,8,6,2
>
> 15,16

What I want is to display a graph given by the adjacency matrix(which I've done using `igraph` package) and vertices in each line of `communities.csv` to be displayed together in this graph and have different colors i.e., all vertices of line1 (11,10,7,4,3) may have red color, all vertices of line2 may have green and so on and vertices in each line must be shown together in the graph, basically I'd prefer random color for each line(community), since number of rows may vary in `communities.csv`.

I'm a noob to R hence have not done much with igraph also, what I have done so far is:

```
library(igraph)

adj.matrix <- read.csv(file = "D:\\communityDetection\\adj.csv", header = FALSE, sep = ",")
adj.matrix<- as.matrix(adj.matrix)
communities <- read.csv(file = "D:\\communityDetection\\communities.csv", header = FALSE, sep = ",")

g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(adj.matrix)
plot(g)
```

I know it's almost nothing but this is all apart from algorithm implementation.

EDIT:

> dput(adj.matrix)

structure(c(0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L,
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L,
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 1L,
1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), .Dim = c(17L, 17L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("V1",
"V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11",
"V12", "V13", "V14", "V15", "V16", "V17")))

> dput(communities)

structure(c(11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 10L, 5L, 9L, 1L, 16L, 7L,
NA, NA, 0L, NA, 4L, NA, NA, 8L, NA, 3L, NA, NA, 6L, NA, NA, NA,
NA, 2L, NA), .Dim = 5:6, .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("V1", "V2",
"V3", "V4", "V5", "V6")))

`dput()` results were requested so here they are

EDIT:

```
library(igraph)
#package to generate random colors
library(randomcoloR)

adj.matrix <- read.csv(file = "D:\\communityDetection\\adj.csv", header = FALSE, sep = ",")
adj.matrix<- as.matrix(adj.matrix)

communities <- read.csv(file = "D:\\communityDetection\\communities.csv", header = FALSE, sep = ",")
communities <- as.matrix(communities)
for(i in 1:nrow(communities))
{
   for(j in 1:ncol(communities))
   {
       if(! is.na(communities[i, j]))
       {
           communities[i, j] <- communities[i, j] + 1
       }
   }
}

d <- c(1:nrow(adj.matrix))
g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(adj.matrix, mode = "undirected", diag = FALSE)
V(g)$name <- d

#colorSpace is a string vector with color names
colorSpace <- distinctColorPalette(k = nrow(communities), altCol = FALSE, runTsne = TRUE)

for(i in 1:nrow(adj.matrix))
{
   for(j in 1:nrow(communities))
   {
       if(V(g)$name[i] %in% communities[j, ])
       {
           V(g)$color[i] = colorSpace[j]
       }
   }
}

plot(g)
```

I've written this code till now, but some of the vertices are filled with wrong color

[like in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZhW6.png)

7 should be green like 11 since they're in same community but is not, is there any syntactical discrepancy. Also nodes are distributed apart is there a way to display nodes with same color together.

Comment: Hi, could you `dput()` your data to have some usable example?

Comment: @nihil check the post I've added the data you requested

Comment: Could you have `colnames(adj.matrix)` with, in place of (`V1, V2`...) the names of the `communities`? There is not any automatic corrispondence so you can do it only manually if you want to display communities.

Comment: Actually there's no worry about community names